# Adding multiple attachments where number of attachments varies

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, email-attachments

I am sending emails out to approximately 150 individuals, each email may have between 1 and 3 attachments.

I can send emails out just fine with one attachment...getting multiple attachments is difficult.

Lets say the attachment file path is located in A1 through C1.

How can I Perform.

If A1 is empty, go to Send, if not, attach file
If B1 is empty, go to Send, if not, attach file
If C1 is empty, go to Send, if not, attach file

Send:

This is the code I have currently: I realize my ranges are different than what I posted above.  The following script works...its just for the one attachment however.

```
Set rngEntries = ActiveSheet.Range("b5:b172")

For Each rngEntry In rngEntries
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    With objMail
        .To = rngEntry.Offset(0, 11).Value
        .Subject = rngEntry.Offset(0, 8).Value
        .Body = rngEntry.Offset(0, 10).Value
        .Attachments.Add rngEntry.Offset(0, 9).Value
        .send
    End With
Next rngEntry
```

What I want would look a little like this....

```
Set rngEntries = ActiveSheet.Range("b5:b172")

For Each rngEntry In rngEntries
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    With objMail
        .To = rngEntry.Offset(0, 11).Value
        .Subject = rngEntry.Offset(0, 8).Value
        .Body = rngEntry.Offset(0, 10).Value

If rngEntry.Offset(0, 1) is empty, goto Send

        .Attachments.Add rngEntry.Offset(0, 1).Value

If rngEntry.Offset(0, 2) is empty, goto Send

        .Attachments.Add rngEntry.Offset(0, 2).Value

If rngEntry.Offset(0, 3) is empty, goto Send

        .Attachments.Add rngEntry.Offset(0, 3).Value

Send: 
        .send
    End With

Next rngEntry
```

Comment: what are the values in rngEntry.Offset(0, 1), rngEntry.Offset(0, 2), and rngEntry.Offset(0, 3)?  At the start of your code, can you concatenate those values together and then put that newly concatenated value is a single argument to add to the .Attachments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always best to avoid `GoTo` statements in VBA at all costs, because things can get hairy very quickly. Just write this:

```
If Not IsEmpty(rngEntry.Offset(0, 1)) Then .Attachments.Add rngEntry.Offset(0, 1).Value

If Not IsEmpty(rngEntry.Offset(0, 2)) Then .Attachments.Add rngEntry.Offset(0, 2).Value

If Not ISEmpty(rngEntry.Offset(0, 3)) then .Attachments.Add rngEntry.Offset(0, 3).Value
```

**Additional Info**

You may also be interested in a function I built to send emails, which passes attachments as a `|` separated string values and then splits them into an array to load them. In this way, you can send one or more with the same function, plus a few other nifty things.

A few notes: I declared Outlook outside the function in the capacity I was using it, so you'd have to either do the same, or add it into the function. It also uses `Early Binding` as I use inside other MS Office Products.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendMail(strTo As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String, strAttachments As String, Optional strCC As String, Optional strFolder As String, Optional blSend As Boolean)
'requires declaration of Outlook Application outside of sub-routine
'passes file name and folder separately
'strAttachments is a "|" separate listed of attachment paths

Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

'login to outlook
Set olNs = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olNs.Logon

'create mail item
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'display mail to get signature
With oMail
    .Display
End With

Dim strSig As String
strSig = oMail.HTMLBody

'build mail and send
With oMail

    .To = strTo
    .CC = strCC
    .Subject = strSubject
    .HTMLBody = strBody & strSig

    Dim strAttach() As String, x As Integer
    strAttach() = Split(strAttachments, "|")

    For x = LBound(strAttach()) To UBound(strAttach())
        If FileExists(strFolder & strAttach(x)) Then .Attachments.Add strFolder & strAttach(x)
    Next

    .Display
    If blSend Then .Send

End With

Set olNs = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is the `FileExists` that checks if the attachment exists before trying to add it:

```
Function FileExists(sFile As String) As Boolean
'requires reference to Microsoft Scripting RunTime

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists(sFile) Then
    FileExists = True
Else
    FileExists = False
End If

Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Your fist "If Not Is" idea is great...I think it will work out well.   I will be seeing if I can make your other code work as well.  Thanks a million.